# manual mapping dll never execute my MessageBoxA function

Tags: windows, assembly, shellcode, dll-injection

I am basically manual mapping my dll into "notepad.exe" am resolving imports, fixing relocations and executing my shellcode in target process which is ("notepad.exe") which should call my dll entry point.

The problem is I tried debugging it for hours now and I can't seem to find the problem and I guess its from my shellcode but I would like to know if there's something wrong with it or not.

Also after debugging the shellcode does actually jump to my DLL entrypoint address and executes but it never calls MessageBoxA and crashes the whole program after my shellcode finishes executing.

Note am injecting a x64 DLL into a x64 process.

My shellcode:

```
BYTE shellcode[] =
{
    // push rax save old register so we don't corrupt it
    0x50,

    // mov rax,0xff00efbeadde00ff <- this value is just
    // a place that will get replaced by our entrypoint pointer 
    0x48, 0xB8, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0x00, 0xFF, 

    // sub rsp,0x28 (align the stack and shadow space allocation)
    0x48, 0x83, 0xEC, 0x28,

    // call rax 
    0xFF, 0xD0,

    // add rsp,0x28
    0x48, 0x83, 0xC4, 0x28,

    // pop rax
    0x58,

    // ret
    0xC3
};
```

Comment: What happens when the entry-point of the DLL is executed? Where does the execution flow go?  Are you sure the DLL is correctly mapped? What if you map it in *your* process and jump to the entry-point, does it work? This will help you spot where the problem is. BTW, you don't have to be sorry about the formatting, just fix it :) there's a "code block" tool.

Comment: @MargaretBloom  the execution goes to my dll entry point in target process and starts executes , am 100% sure that my dll is correctly mapped and has fixed both imports and base relocations. but do you see anything wrong in my shellcode? am aligning the stack properly and returning at the end of my shellcode. now i tried to run it again in release mode it didn't crash my application but MessageBoxA did not get called.

Comment: The shellcode seems correct to me (but I trusted your comments). I usually debug crashes by looking at the address of the faulting instruction and by stepping the program with a debugger (not entering inside the APIs, of course). x64dbg is a very good debugger if you need one. You can put a breakpoint just before the main program resume notepad.exe and once this hits, another breakpoint in the shellcode in nodepad.exe and keep debugging from there.

Comment: @MargaretBloom thanks i already debugged it but now after debugging it for a while i found out that there is a `cmp edx,1` before the call to any winapi function inside my dll and then a jump if not equal and for some reason it will always take that jmp and never executes my function which is MessageBoxA inside my dll now i tried to nop both the compare instruction and the jmp call and going to call the winapi function then it magically worked i saw the box pop up. but the question is if it worked it means that i have a working fixed image so the problem is not from my code can you suggest?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's impossible to help you without a [MCVE]. I'm not even sure I understood who, and where, put those `cmp edx, 1` and jump instructions.

Comment: @MargaretBloom i kinda solved the problem by hardcoding the address where this compare instruction is and setting rdx to 1 bit then it will pass that check and will call my dll just fine. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I was trying this. Check the disassembly before the `cmp edx, 1` instruction. I suspect the compare is checking to ensure the base address is correct. Assuming thats true, you have to add some code to your manual loader to ensure the base address is set properly so this comparison can pass without having to nop it out.